# Is it possible to have a separate remote desktop VNC for each workspace?

Tags: remote

For example suppose my IP address is 192.168.1.1

Would I be able to have

192.168.1.1:5901 connecting to workspace 1
192.168.1.1:5902 connecting to workspace 2

etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it in case of FreeVNC.

You can find a discussion about this in [this superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/32455/virtual-vnc-screen-workspace).